# Android - change string local programmatically

Tags: android, internationalization

I want the user to be able to change a translation in an Android App and store the new value local resources instead of the old one. Is there a way to achieve this operation, storing a new local programmatically in Android ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add a new Locale  programmatically.(This is a guess i will check and confirm)

Theoretically you can do some thing else.

You can save the strings in db for required locale using your code.

Add in your components onCreate you can match the locale and replace the string.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm still crawling in the documentation looking for some way to programmatically set it :(

Comment: After looking for a long period, I can say that as far as I've looked there is no possibility to do so